# How to run perl xt tests?

Tags: perl, xt, perl-prove

Lately the new great thing appeared in the Perl world. For a long time in the 
library package there was folder `t` that contained tests. Now there is one 
more folder `xt` that contains author test. The `xt` tests are not needed in
the process of the library installation, but it helps library autor to make
sure that the code is great.

There is a spript `prove` that ships with the Perl that runs test. If you run 
`prove` without parameters all tests from the folder 't' will be executed. If
you want to run both `t` and `xt` test you should write:

```
prove xt t
```

It it possible to add to the configuration file `.proverc` file that
parameters (`xt t`). Then when you run `prove` without parameters they will be
taken from file and tests in the both folders will be executed.

But here comes the problem. In case you have `xt t` in your `.proverc` file
you can't just pass the filename as the parameter to the `prove`. If you say 
`prove t/00-load.t` it will execute all the tests in both folders, because
it takes parameters from config file. You need to write `prove --norc
t/00-load.t`. But this seems ugly.

How do you run your `xt` tests?

Comment: What about adding a target to the Makefile? The "ugly" code can be hidden there, while you just enter `make xt`.

Answer (score 2):

Author tests should not be run by default - you don't want a CPAN install to fail because some of your POD syntax is wrong. They should ideally be run on release, when specifically requested.

See http://elliotlovesperl.com/2009/11/24/explicitly-running-author-tests/ for a method involving Module::Build.

I sometimes use [Dist::Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist%3a%3aZilla), which handles author tests by default.

Answer (score 1):

I add

```
package MY;
sub depend {
  "
xtest :: test
    \$(MAKE) test TEST_FILES=xt/*.t
"
}
```

to `Makefile.PL`.
This runs the normals tests, and then the `xt` tests.